# Calculate centrality score from weighted edge list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, networkx

```
I have a dataframe, which is a weighted edge list: 

 from A to B weight 
   1     2     1
   3     5     1
   1     4     1
   4     1     3
   1     3     2
   6     2     1
```

I am new to the concept of networks, nodes, centrality score etc

I am trying to calculate centrality score from this weighted edge list.

Anything can help. A solution, link to somewhere I can refer to, or just any comments. Thanks!

Comment: are edges directional? Are you looking for degree centrality or something else (betweenness, eigenvector, etc)?

Comment: in general, you'd probably want to use a dedicated graph package like `networkx` (easier to learn) or `networkit` (works faster)

Comment: @Marat . Yes they are directional edges. Looking for various factors, such as degree centrality, betweenness etc. Essentially trying to get an overall view of the relationships

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times the best available documentation on networkx is reading its sources. Here is a not-so-obvious example:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'from A': [1,3,1,4,1,6], 'to B': [2,5,4,1,3,2], 'weight': [1,1,1,3,2,1]})

graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from A', 'to B', ['weight'], create_using=nx.DiGraph)
graph.degree(weight='weight')  # DiDegreeView({1: 7, 2: 2, 3: 3, 5: 1, 4: 4, 6: 1})
```